# Backbone: Storing collection in model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to store a Backbone Collection inside a Backbone Model, but it's not working. Instead of actually storing the Collection object, and array is stored.

```
var modelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        collection: null
    }
});

var modelB = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var CollectionA = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: modelA
});

var CollectionB = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: modelB
});

var myCollection = new CollectionA();

myCollection.create({
    collection: new CollectionB()
});
```

Is there something wrong or is this not working with Backbone out of the box?

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in posted code. Notably in, `var collectionA` and `collectionB`, should be `CollectionA` and `CollectionB`. Then you have a semi-colon in the object you pass to `create`.

Comment: @fbynite Thanks for the heads up! I added them by accident while simplifying the testcase.

Comment: Cool, you may want to check [Nested Models & Collections](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested) as well, if you haven't already.

Comment: @fbynite Wow, thank you! No, I didn't knew this, this is great!

Comment: I don't see from the code how you are trying to store a collection inside of a Model. Are you trying to store an instance of CollectionB inside an instance of CollectionA?

Comment: @PeterWagener Thats exactly what I try to do. Indeed it's phrased not precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems off.  Is this what you are trying to do?  This is an example of storing Models inside a collection, then the collection inside a model:

```
var ModelWithCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        typicalCollection: null
    }
});

var TypicalModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var TypicalCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TypicalModel 
});
//create some model instances
var typicalModelA = new TypicalModel();
var typicalModelB = new TypicalModel();
//create typical collection instance and add models
var myCollection = new TypicalCollection([typicalModelA, typicalModelB]);

//now create a model with a collection
var modelWithCollection = new ModelWithCollection({typicalCollection:myCollection});
```